# In iOS, should I be committing files with a `.a` file extension to my mercurial repository?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mercurial, hgignore

I am fairly new to iOS development. I am using the iOS Admob SDK. When I tried to commit my changes to Mercurial I received the following message:

```
<working_dir>/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.0/libGoogleAdMobAds.a: up to 39 MB of RAM may be required to manage this file
(use 'hg revert <working_dir>/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.0/libGoogleAdMobAds.a' to cancel the pending addition)
```

Should I be committing files ending in `.a` to the repository or should I include it to `.hgignore`?

Comment: Generally, you should never commit things to the source code repository which are the product of the build. `.a` files are typically a product of the build, and as such should not be committed. There *are* exceptions, but the general rule is if the file wasn't there when you started the build but ended up there after the build then it shouldn't be committed.

Answer (score -1):

IMO you should use Cocoapods and do not commit vendor libraries in your repository instead just push Podfile (if needed Podfile.lock) into your repo.

Read more about Cocoapods here -
http://cocoapods.org/

For AdMob SDK here is how you can install it using Cocoapod - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#streamlined_using_cocoapods

Comment: Not sure why anyone would vote down this answer? Wasn't this helpful?